# Linq to Sql - Repository Pattern - Dynamic OrderBy

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Ok, I found [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), which will allow me to do this:

```
public IList<Item> GetItems(string orderbyColumn)
{
    return _repository.GetItems().OrderBy(orderByColumn).ToList();
}
```

Is this the best way to do "dynamic" ordering?  I want to be able to pass the column name as a string (and the sort direction) to my Service, and have it order the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just after dynamic sorting without the full Dynamic-Linq stuff you can check out a post I wrote about this a while back: [click](http://blog.invalidoperation.com/2011/07/linq-to-sql-and-objectdatasource-bff.html)

EDIT: I don't really blog anymore so here's the actual extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string sortExpression) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
            return source; // nothing to sort on

        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
        string ascSortMethodName = "OrderBy";
        string descSortMethodName = "OrderByDescending";            
        string[] sortExpressionParts = sortExpression.Split(' ');
        string sortProperty = sortExpressionParts[0];
        string sortMethod = ascSortMethodName;

        if (sortExpressionParts.Length > 1 && sortExpressionParts[1] == "DESC")
            sortMethod = descSortMethodName;    

        var property = entityType.GetProperty(sortProperty);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(
                                            typeof(Queryable), 
                                            sortMethod, 
                                            new Type[] { entityType, property.PropertyType },
                                            source.Expression, 
                                            Expression.Quote(orderByExp));

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExp);
    }
```

Comment: Seems as if the blog entry is a dead link.  @ray2k... can you update it?

Comment: Done. http://blog.invalidoperation.com/2011/07/linq-to-sql-and-objectdatasource-bff.html

Comment: Looks like the new link is dead as well. Could you possible repost the solution here inside your answer?

Answer (score 9):

That's certainly a viable way of doing dynamic sorting. [Ch00k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489/ch00k) provided another option in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557819/strongly-typed-dynamic-linq-sorting/560161#560161) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557819/strongly-typed-dynamic-linq-sorting) about "Strongly typed dynamic Linq sorting". I personally prefer Ch00k's method, as there's some compile-time checking involved and there's very little extra code involved.

Comment: And his answer (Ch00k) will be refactoring-safe as well, do a rename of a property, and the code updates, with the property name in a string, that won't happen!

Answer (score 4):

If you've already decided that it must be a string, then your options are somewhat limited. The Dynamic LINQ library would indeed do the job, or if you want t know how it all works, look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505) which builds an `Expression` from the string at runtime.

At the moment the code only accepts a single member and has separate methods for ascending / descending, but from this example it should be fairly simple to pass a more complex string and split it; essentially as:

```
IQueryable<T> query = ...
string[] portions = orderBy.Split(' '); // split on space, arbitrarily
if(portions.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException();
IOrderedQueryable<T> orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(portions[0]);
for(int i = 1 ; i < portions.Length ; i++) { // note we already did the zeroth
    orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(portions[i]);
}
return orderedQuery;
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a string, but how would I pass the sort column from the controller to the Repository/Service?

Comment: If not a string, then the only other sensible choice would be a lambda Expression, or an object that encapsulates more than one lambda expression. Or just use the existing OrderBy/ThenBy.