# how can i pass parameter to linq query

Tags: linq-to-sql

i want to pass parameter to linq query...

```
public IEnumerable GetPhotos()
{
    PhotoDBDataContext db = new PhotoDBDataContext();
    var query = from p in db.Photos
                orderby p.PhotoId descending
                select new { p.Album, p.AlbumId, p.Description, p.Photographer,
                             p.PhotographerId, p.PhotoId, p.Tags, p.Thumbnail,
                             p.Url };
    return query;
}
```

in above example "orderby p.PhotoId descending" is used, i want to  use parameter in place of p.PhotoId

is it possible...

Comment: The `select new { ... }` seems to be fairly comprehensive. Are you really selecting a subset of all columns? If not, you could just write `select p`.

Comment: You are not using `tProduct` anywhere. What is its purpose?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747114/linq-to-entities-dynamic-sorting/2747641#2747641

Answer (score 3):

```
public IQueryable<Photo> GetPhotos(PhotoDBDataContext db, string orderBy)
{
    var query = from p in db.Photos select p;
    switch (orderBy) {
        case "PhotoId":
            return query.OrderBy(p => p.PhotoId);
        case "AlbumId":
            return query.OrderBy(p => p.AlbumId);
        default:
            // Error handling.
    } 
}
```

Note that you should not return objects with an anonymous type.

Comment: can we use lamdaexpression here?

Answer (score 1):

With [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx), you can write `.OrderBy("ColumnName")`.

Comment: +1 for the dynamic linq and the 5th use case for DL that I have seen here in the past 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, there have been quite a lot questions about sorting LINQ queries lately.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this if you had two order-by criteria

```
    public static IQueryable<Photo> GetPhotos(string OrderBy)
    {
        return db.Photos.OrderBy(p => ( (OrderBy == "PhotoId") ? (p.PhotoId) : (p.AlbumId) ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension. This helped me:

```
public static class OrderExt
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<T> Order<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, SortDirection descending, bool anotherLevel = false)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty);
            var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
            var sort = Expression.Lambda(property, param);

            var call = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                (!anotherLevel ? "OrderBy" : "ThenBy") +
                (descending == SortDirection.Descending ? "Descending" : string.Empty),
                new[] { typeof(T), property.Type },
                source.Expression,
                Expression.Quote(sort));

            return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
        }
    }
```

For full explanation you could go to: http://how-to-code-net.blogspot.ro/2014/04/how-to-call-for-dynamic-orderby-method.html