# Translate LINQ Statement to usual Data Service URL

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, url

I want to translate a simple LINQ statement to a url that I can use on my webserver to produce my output manually. So I want to get something like this

```
http://localhost:6627/WebSite15/NorthwindDataService.svc/Products?$orderby=ProductName
```

when executing a statement like:

```
Products.Orderby(x => x.ProductName);
```

Is this possible? I mean, a simple data service does that out of the box, but I don't want to use this thing because I have special requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized it with a ExpressionVisitor now. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and I found this [EntitySorter](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=66) and it worked wonderfully... You can see a similar implementation of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747114/linq-to-entities-dynamic-sorting) also (look at the higher voted answer, not the marked answer).

It would let you do this kind of thing:

```
IEntitySorter<Person> sorter = EntitySorter<Person>
    .OrderBy("Address.City")
    .ThenByDescending("Id");
```

EDIT: On a side note, I had a perfectly justified reason to use it (and in fact was using it in a mocked service layer so I wasn't concerned about performance), but it was remarkable how much EntitySorter has to "go around your a$$ to get to your elbow" to get soft searches working... I think it was Microsoft's attempt at saying "We didn't make this easy on purpose"... That said, I thought EntitySorter was a very elegant solution considering what it's doing :)

Comment: Hm. I don't see the point where I can convert this to the url above.

Comment: EntitySorter would let you do lamda sorting from a string... You would just need to search the Request.QueryString to get the OrderBy value.

Comment: Thats not what I meant. What I meant was just translating the above command to a url.