# How to infer TResult from the actual Type?

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-entities, type-inference

I am using the Entity Framework, ASP.NET and C#3.5
I borrowed the following code to make sorting possible using a sortExpression from a GridView instead of the property of an entity:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string sortExpression)
    {
        string[] sortParts = sortExpression.Split(' ');
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty);

        var property = Expression.Property(param, sortParts[0]);

        var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)), param);           

        if (sortParts.Length > 1 && sortParts[1].Equals("desc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending(sortLambda);
        }

        return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy(sortLambda);
    }
```

The problem is that LINQ to Entities does not support casting to object. Instead of Func, I need the actual return type instead of object. I worked out how to do it:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string sortExpression)
    {
        string[] sortParts = sortExpression.Split(' ');
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty);

        var property = Expression.Property(param, sortParts[0]);

        // NEW CODE HERE
        Type propertyType = property.Type;
        Type lambdaType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), propertyType);
        var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(property, propertyType), param);
        //var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)), param);

        if (sortParts.Length > 1 && sortParts[1].Equals("desc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending(sortLambda);
        }

        return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy(sortLambda);
    }
```

The problem now is that if I have an Int32, it will not cast to object, which is still the return type. I worked around it like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string sortExpression)
    {
        string[] sortParts = sortExpression.Split(' ');
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), string.Empty);

        var property = Expression.Property(param, sortParts[0]);

        // New code here
        Type propertyType = property.Type;
        Type lambdaType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), propertyType);

        // NEWEST CODE HERE
        var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda(lambdaType, Expression.Convert(property, propertyType), param);
        //var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(property, propertyType), param);
        //var sortLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)), param);


        if (sortParts.Length > 1 && sortParts[1].Equals("desc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending(sortLambda);
        }

        return source.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy(sortLambda);
    }
```

This however does not compile any longer. The error is:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The problem is that I do not want to specify the type arguments explicitly.

Does anyone know how to work around this or anyhow infer the TResult type from "propertyType"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby/233505#233505), with the [refinement here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469531/linq-to-sql-repository-pattern-dynamic-orderby/1489207#1489207), should do what you need. By necessity it uses reflection to do the guts in the middle, but it works. Note also that `Expression.GetFuncType` and `Expression.GetActionType` can avoid some of the work in your approach.