# How to perform LINQ OrderBy based on a stringname for column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

If I had

```
public ActionResult ListExpenseItems(long id)
{
            IQueryable<I_ITEM> expenseItems = er.GetExpenseItems(id);
            return PartialView(expenseItems );
}
```

and the LINQ

```
public IQueryable<I_ITEM> GetExpenseItems(long id)
{
            return from i in db.I_ITEM
                   where i.ExpenseId == id
                   orderby i.ExpenseItemId ascending
                   select i;
 }
```

If I passed a string in as a parameter to the LINQ method, say `"ExpenseTitle"`, how would I do `OrderBy i.ExpenseTitle` so that orderby always matches the string parameter?

This kind of logic.. but actually correct:

```
db.I_ITEM.OrderBy(x => (orderBy == 'date') ? x.Date : (orderBy == 'id') ? x.Id : (orderBy == 'cost') ? x.Cost : x.Id);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify the Linq OrderBy argument dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265186/how-do-i-specify-the-linq-orderby-argument-dynamically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this previous questions might solve your problem

[Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

[Strongly typed dynamic Linq sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

or you can use the Dynamic Linq library.

Comment: Both those links go to the same question. I think the second one is looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/557819/2449863