# Pass Parameter on Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is it possible to pass the parameter after the period on a LINQ Query?

For example on this code:

```
objResultFinal = objResultFinal.OrderByDescending(x => x.[iwanttopassparameterhere]).ToList();
```

Is that possible? I want to declare after the "x." the string that I want to query.

Comment: What do you mean by passing a parameter? Do you mean accessing a property?

Comment: Yes accessing the property by passing it as parameter. Example:

string strToPass = "myProperty"

Then on LINQ Query:

x => x.strToPass

Is that possible? I want to dynamically query on LINQ and I am not sure what property is to filter yet.

Comment: This is not a valid syntax: `x.[iwanttopassparameterhere]`. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Do you want the actual property to be a parameter?

Comment: Yes the property to be a parameter.

Comment: You can do it by reflection

Comment: If you're quering the database then check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7265354/3185569 . If you're querying in-memory list then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7265394/3185569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objResultFinal.OrderByDescending(s => s.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName").GetValue(s, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be done using dynamic LINQ as below -

```
objResultFinal.OrderBy(passYourParameterHere).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list is that of type `object`? You'd either have to cast it first or use reflection.

Using **casting**:

```
var sortedList = objectList.Cast<Email>().OrderByDescending(item => item.EmailAddress).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();

list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "V" });
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "B" });
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "A" });
list.Add(new MyClass { Name = "C" });

//Create expression here, IF YOU ARE SORTING ON STRING PROPERTY KEEP KEY AS STRING OR CHANGE TO RESPECTIVE DATA TYPE
Func<MyClass,string> expression = s=>s.Name;

var ordered = list.OrderByDescending(expression).ToList();
```

**The Class Object**

```
class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```