# Is there a way I could change a LINQ query orderBy depending on a parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

I coded two LINQ statements with different orderBy.  Is there a way that I could change the orderBy without having to code twice like this:

```
        if (param == "s")
        {
            var result = await db.PhraseCategories
                                 .OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder)
                                 .Select(p => new
                                 {
                                     Id = p.PhraseCategoryShortId,
                                     Name = p.Name
                                 })
                                 .AsNoTracking()
                                 .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(result);
        } 

        if (param == "n")
        {
            var result = await db.PhraseCategories
                 .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                 .Select(p => new
                 {
                     Id = p.PhraseCategoryShortId,
                     Name = p.Name
                 })
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Comment: define a predicate as a var/property, and use it once ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other option can be to work on *query* like:

```
IQueryable<PhraseCategory> query = db.PhraseCategories;

// Order as needed
if(param == "s")
    query = query.OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder);
else if(param == "n")
    query = query.OrderBy(m => m.Name);

var result = await query
    .Select(p => new
    {
     Id = p.PhraseCategoryShortId,
     Name = p.Name
    })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();     
return Ok(result);
```

Additionally, if you can get `param` in the form of *property name* to order according to, then you can write extension method to dynamically order according to property name as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265354/1380428).

Comment: I like this too.  We use this approach internally to _progressively_ add further sorts to a query, according to whether the user has selected extra sub-sorts.  IE continue to apply extra `.ThenBy()` clauses to a query, before execution, for each extra sub-sort a user has selected.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = await db.PhraseCategories
    .OrderBy(p => param == "s" ? p.SortOrder : p.Name)
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Id = p.PhraseCategoryShortId,
        Name = p.Name
    })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

return Ok(result);
```

Comment: You could of course code more precisely for `param == "n"` rather than just use the 'else' half of `? :`, if you wish.  Your original code sample didn't indicate what would happen if `param` matched neither `"n"` nor `"s"`

Comment: good option, for 2 , but not for more ... back to defining the predicate i'm afraid

Comment: @Noctis  perfectly possible for more than 2, with nested `? :` - but not very readable.  For more than 2, I would probably, like you, go with pulling the sorting logic out into a predicate beforehand.

Comment: if you start nesting `? :` you're in almost the same place where you started (bit better, but still not easy to read). Might be what Alan needs though