# Linq orderby StringComparer dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

From my previous question. [C# Linq OrderBy(x => x.property)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151219/c-sharp-linq-orderbyx-x-property)

I specified my linq orderby argument dynamically.

```
var param = “attribute1”;    
var propertyInfo = typeof(data).GetProperty(param);    
List<data> newList = _list
  .OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null))
  .ToList();
```

the problem is when I want to order this by StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase:

```
List<data> newList = _list
  .OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToList();
```

I receive this error:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IComparer)' cannot be inferred from
>   the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

By not making it dynamic works. But I want this to order the dynamic argument.

```
List<data> newList = _list
  .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: So you want to order numbers by string ordinal case?

Comment: Why you use this reflection approach if you only support string properties?

Comment: I also support this with integer and I use convert to convert string to integer.

Comment: Did you tried to pass your `data` type to your `OrderBy`? `OrderBy` method is also generic method, so probably you can pass `data` to it -> `OrderBy<data, data>()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `propertyInfo.GetValue` returns `Object` (not `String`) you have a syntax error. Try casting to `String`:

```
List<data> newList = _list
  .OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null) as String,
           StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Call `ToString()` on the result of `GetValue()`:

```
List<data> newList = _list
  .OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null).ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Has the advantage that it "works " also for other types like `int`. But then you always have lexicographical order. `10` < `2`. Throws an exception if the property returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As GetValue method has object as return type. so we need to typecast it to String and will resolve your issue.

```
  newList.OrderBy(x => (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

try it out. hope it will work.