# C# - Order By property by reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, entity

I have a database query providing me *IQueryable* object where *T* is anonymous data type like this:

```
var baseListQuery = (<...> select new {
    note = n, // class Note
    triggers = grp // class Trigger
})
```

Now I would like to sort this by different properties of *Note* (e.g. *Note.Title*) but my *Note* class can contain plenty of different properties. Property to be used as sorting element can be changed externaly and information about which one to use I will receive as a simple string. Currently I am using *switch-case* statement to evaluate received string and then select appropriate property to sort:

```
switch(SortBy) {
    ...
    case "Title": baseListQuery = baseListQuery.OrderBy(p => p.note.Title); break;
    ...
}
```

However, I am wondering if it is possible to to it in more general way, using reflection? I would like to check if *Note* contains property with the name of received string and if so, sort results appropriately. I have tried something like this:

```
var baseQueryType = baseListQuery.GetType();
var member = (baseQueryType.GetGenericArguments()[0]).GetProperty("note");
var member2 = member.PropertyType.GetProperty("Title"); // I would like to use GetProperty(SortBy);
baseListQuery = baseListQuery.OrderBy(p => member2);
```

Which will raise exception when calling for example *baseListQuery.Count()*:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'
```

Is it possible to do this with reflection, and if so, can somebody explain me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are various implementations of Dynamic Linq that do things similar to what you want. Search for them in nuget.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265354/1663001) is a good way to do this without resorting to Dynamic Linq

Comment: @DavidG Just tried this with a little modification for properties nested deeper in hierarchy and seems that proposed approach solved my problem. What a nice solution. Thank You.

Comment: Great to hear. Not my solution though, be sure to vote on the link in question :)