# ThenBy fails after Select

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I'm trying to Order my main table(Contract) by some value in another table (via Join) then reduce it to Contracts again and sort it (ThenBy) by a value in Contract.

Here's the short version of my question:
Is it possible to reduce a composite Anonymous type (produced by a Join) to a defined type without turning my IOrderedQueryable into an IQueryable?

Long version of the question with example:

My production code is quite complex but for the purpose of this question I've broken it down to a simple example:

```
static void simple()
{
  bool condition = true;

  var ctx = new LxDataContext();

  IQueryable<Contract> q1 = ctx.Contracts.Join(ctx.ContractDetails, c => c.ContractId, cd => cd.ContractId, (c, cd) => new { c, cd }).
                            Where(J => J.cd.DetailNo > 0).
                            Select(J => J.c);

  IOrderedQueryable<Contract> qOrdered;

  if (condition)
  {
    qOrdered = (IOrderedQueryable<Contract>)q1.Join(ctx.ContractPartners, c => c.ContractId, cp => cp.ContractId, (c, cp) => new { c, cp }).
               Join(ctx.VwPartners, J => J.cp.PartnerId, p => p.PartnerId, (J, p) => new { J.c, p }).
               OrderBy(J => J.p.LastName).
               Select(J => J.c);
  }
  else
    qOrdered = q1.OrderBy(c => c.Premium);

  IOrderedQueryable<Contract> qReady = (qOrdered).ThenBy(c => c.ContractId); //if condition == true exception here

  var dump = qReady.Skip(50).Take(50).ToList();
}
```

When condition is false everything works as excepted.
However when the more complex OrderBy() is executed the ThenBy() fails with this exception:

```
Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[InfoServiceTests.DB.Contract]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[InfoServiceTests.DB.Contract]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[InfoServiceTests.DB.Contract] ThenBy[Contract,Int32](System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[InfoServiceTests.DB.Contract], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[InfoServiceTests.DB.Contract,System.Int32]])'
```

So even though I cast it to IOrderedQueryable<> qOrdered doesn't seem to be IOrderedQueryable<> and ThenBy() fails. Is it possible to sort by something in another table then reduce the result to Contract and ThenBy-sort it again?

Some comments:
 - If it's any help to you: In my production code i have a generic sorting class mostly taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557819/strongly-typed-dynamic-linq-sorting/2794039#2794039).
 - Yes I know the example could easily be fixed, but in my Production code I need a generic solution for sorting by user-defined values. This invloves looping and passing the Queryables around to functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Condition is OK you should add some ordering becausae after select your query is not ordered query and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby.aspx) just works after ordered query:

> Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in
> ascending order.

for example in your true condition you can do (in your if condition):

```
qOrdered = (IOrderedQueryable<Contract>)q1
           .Join(ctx.ContractPartners, 
            c => c.ContractId, cp => cp.ContractId, (c, cp) => new { c, cp }).
            Join(ctx.VwPartners, J => J.cp.PartnerId, 
                 p => p.PartnerId, (J, p) => new { J.c, p }).
               OrderBy(J => J.p.LastName).ThenBy(J=>J.ContractId)
               Select(J => J.c);
```

and you can do (in your else statement):

```
qOrdered = q1.OrderBy(c => c.Premium).ThenBy(c=>c.ContractId);
```

Also you should remove your current ThenBy operation after your if statements.

In fact you  should find something which is orderable and OrderBy it, then use ThenBy.

Comment: I thought about that but `OrderBy(J => J.c)` doesn't work as J.c refers to Contract wich is a class without a comparer. And using another OrderBy would negate all previous ones.

Comment: You fixed the problem for my example, unfortunately in my real code I have to pass my half-finished queries around to function that sort/filter further, join with another table, prepare the data for paging, etc.

Comment: @NULL you should do many tasks, but you can't change `ThenBy` definition, so you should change all of your tasks if you want use it.

Comment: I now used a dirty hack to get what I wanted. Your answer provided me with some ideas, even though it didn't work in the end.

Comment: @NULL what's your dirty code? and why it doesn't handles what you want?

Comment: The dirty code is having some ifs that change the queries the way I need them to be in my main methods. It does what I want now. What I meant is that my ideas about an elegant solution didn't work.

Comment: @NULL I suggest manage all of your query again, find their relevant part, If they are separated, write different method for each of them, and put common part of them in other methods, more elegant way I can think is this, in all, there are too many situation which we can't create very simple answer, but we can simplified it, but named method.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in your if to:

```
qOrdered = (IOrderedQueryable<Contract>)q1.Join(ctx.ContractPartners, c => c.ContractId, cp => cp.ContractId, (c, cp) => new { c, cp }).
               Join(ctx.VwPartners, J => J.cp.PartnerId, p => p.PartnerId, (J, p) => new { J.c, p }).
               Select(J => J.c).
               OrderBy(J => J.p.LastName)
```

This will return an IOrderedQueryable. If the Select is add the end, you will get a normal IQueryable which can't be ordered with a ThenBy

Comment: after the select J.p isn't available anymore, I could include it in the select but then I would be right were I started.